# How to know if asp.net 3.5 sp1 and asp.net mvc are installed in the server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, installation, production-environment

When I use:

```
System.Environment.Version
```

The result is "2.0.50727.3053"

I know that 3.5 is compatible and in IIS is identified as 2.0, blah blah...

I would like to know the exact .net version installed and if another resources are installed, like ASP.NET MVC, etc. **The problem is that the website is installed in a shared hosting, so I can ask about that resouces to tech support, but if I know programatically, its far better.**

Regards

Comment: I like this question, especially because of the shared hosting caveat that will probably rule out most of the file system and registry based solutions!

Comment: If you like a question, upvote it.

Comment: Sorry, a bit new here.
I did add it as a favourite!

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question. You can bin deploy MVC if you know that 3.5 is installed. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Not sure but try something like this:

```
bool mvcInstalled = true;

try
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(
        "System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35");
}
catch()
{
    mvcInstalled = false;
}
```

**UPDATED:**

To know if .NET 3.5 SP1 is installed check for System.Web.Abstractions assembly

Comment: I like this solution.  This could be really useful in many situations, not just MVC.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC is not built into Microsoft .NET framework 3.5 SP1.

[See this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/14/aspnetmvc-not-in-sp1.aspx)

> I wanted to clear up a bit of
>   confusion I’ve seen around the web
>   about ASP.NET MVC and the .NET
>   Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1. ASP.NET
>   MVC was not released as part of SP1. I
>   repeat, ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 does not
>   include ASP.NET MVC.
>
> What was released with SP1 was the
>   ASP.NET Routing feature, which is in
>   use by both ASP.NET MVC and Dynamic
>   Data.

So there you have it, from the horse's mouth (Haacked again ;).

Comment: Are you sure about this?
I am certain that ASP.NET MVC was a seperate installer that required .NET 3.5 SP1 as a pre-requisite.

Comment: That is not correct. ASP.net URL Routing was baked in, and MVC uses it heavily - but MVC is still a seperate install even if you have 3.5 SP1. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s57a598e.aspx#ASPNETSP1

Comment: In case anyone needs it - the MVC install link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you are mixing up the compiler/run time version with the framework versions.

Running System.Environment.Version will get you 2.0 - which is true - but that is not what you are looking for.

Are you looking for a one time answer or something to be used over and over? If you truly want to know - upload a sample MVC app and see if it runs. Otherwise you are going to have to programmatically inspect what is installed on the machine you are running on.

Comment: something to be used over and over... I install a ton of little asp.net websites and it's a nice info to know before install...